# Google Custom Search wrong count and few results

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I have added Google Custom Search to my website, the problem I am having is the number of results returned by Google search are wrong, on the first page it shows lets say 100 results but as you go to page 5, the result count changes to 50. Is there a way we can avoid this behaviour?

Second problem is the number of pages indexed by Google [if you do a search query site:site.com] which is approximately equal to the number of pages on my website. But if I search for a term it returns less results. My site is on wordpress so if a author has 500 articles it returns only 100 results.

I am using both the Google Custom Search and the Google Search API but the results are same for both.